# optimisation of time test on Maven by testing only modified files?

Tags: junit, maven-2, automated-tests, pdfbox, regression-testing

I'm working on pdfBox project, and I try to test different version (revision) of the project and I would like to reduce testing time by running only test that include modified files ?  Is there any solution ? 
(I just started working with Maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea. A change in one file may have an effect on other (unchanged) files.

If your wish is to save time, then do this instead: run maven with -DskipTests and it will not run the tests.

Besides, even if tests fail, the PDFBox devs will already know it, because a test failure on the build server triggers a mail on the developers mailing list.

Comment: Actually I'm searching Regression bugs in different project, and testing different revision took too much time. Maybe you have faced failed test regression before ?

Comment: Yes... (in the PDFBox JIRA, search for the label "regression" and you'll see some of ours). It takes up to hours to find "the" version that introduced the problem, if it isn't an obvious problem. I try a binary search strategy, get a version, build it without testing, then run my test, write down, decide new version, etc. It might be a bit easier if you are using git, then you can use git bisect.